How to retrieve the code verifier using Keycloak from Angular
I am trying to develop an application with Angular as front, and Java as backend.
I need to login via Keycloak, and then send the received code to the back, to generate the token and store it in the session of the application server.
I am using keycloak-angular 16.1.0 and keycloak-js 25.0.6.
So far, I successfully redirect login to Keycloak using this initialization:
this.keycloak.init({
            config: {
                url: json.keycloakURL,
                realm: json.keycloakRealm,
                clientId: json.keycloakClientId,
            },
            initOptions: {
                checkLoginIframe: false,
                redirectUri: this.baseURI + '-angular/login',
                flow: 'standard', // Use Authorization Code Flow
                pkceMethod: 'S256' // PKCE for additional security
            },
            enableBearerInterceptor: true, // Automatically attach tokens to HTTP requests
            bearerPrefix: 'Bearer'
        });

And then, I login using:
this.keycloak.login({});

Everything works fine, I get my code and send it to the backend. However, I need also a code verifier, or I get an error "PKCE code verifier not specified".
I of course would like to stick to the maximum security possible, so I wouldn't like to disable code verification unless mandatory.
Is there any way I can retrieve this code verifier from the keycloak variable in Angular? Am I missing any important point?
Edit: To summarize and try to make it more clear:
My problem resides not on the Angular side, but on the backend Java side.
I only have the client secret on the backend (Java), so I cannot retrieve the token on the Angular front.
I send the code to the backend, so that the token can be retrieved using the secret. But I don't have the code verifier.

Maybe the architecture is not the right one, but it's what I've understood to be the best option from what I've read. I'd be glad to hear more options if this isn't the right one.

In the end, if you want to configure the secret in the backend, you need to create two different clients.

One for the frontend, public, without secret, to retrieve the code and the token.
One for the backend, confidential, with secret, to get the information from the received token.

Following this blog helped me a lot to understanding it:
Secure Frontend (React.js) and Backend (Node.js/Express Rest API) with Keycloak

Keycloak.js handles the code verifier and code challenge generation for PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) automatically when you use it with the pkceMethod option in the initOptions.
When you set the pkceMethod to 'S256', Keycloak.js performs the following steps internally
Keycloak.js does not expose the code verifier directly through its API. The code verifier is managed internally by the library for security reasons and is not intended to be accessed directly
Next problem is may be CORS issue
Keycloak's server runs on a different port (example , http://localhost:8080) than your Angular app (example http://localhost:4200).
Since these are considered different origins, browsers enforce CORS restrictions.
By setting up a proxy in Angular (proxy.conf.json), you can route API requests to the Keycloak server through the Angular development server, making it appear as though both are coming from the same origin.
Demo
File Tree
C:.
│   angular.json
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.app.json
│   tsconfig.json
│   tsconfig.spec.json
│
├───public
│       favicon.ico
│
└───src
    │   index.html
    │   main.ts
    │   proxy.conf.json
    │   styles.css
    │
    └───app
        │   app.component.css
        │   app.component.html
        │   app.component.spec.ts
        │   app.component.ts
        │   app.config.ts
        │   app.routes.ts
        │   custom-keycloak-guard.ts
        │
        ├───home
        │       home.component.css
        │       home.component.html
        │       home.component.spec.ts
        │       home.component.ts
        │
        └───login
                login.component.css
                login.component.html
                login.component.spec.ts
                login.component.ts

app.config.js - partial, full code is bellow
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: '/auth',     // Use the proxy to route requests
        realm: 'my-realm',
        clientId: 'my-client',
      },
      initOptions: {
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        pkceMethod: 'S256',
        flow: 'standard',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200', // Your's redirectUri: `${baseURI}-angular/login`
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer'      
    });
}

proxy.conf.json
{
  "/auth": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/auth": ""
    }
  }
}

angular.json
        "serve": {
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }
        },

custom-keycloak-guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomKeycloakAuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(protected override router: Router, protected override keycloakAngular: KeycloakService) {
    super(router, keycloakAngular);
  }

  async isAccessAllowed(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const isLoggedIn = await this.keycloakAngular.isLoggedIn();

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.keycloakAngular.login();
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}

app.route.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { CustomKeycloakAuthGuard } from './custom-keycloak-guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [CustomKeycloakAuthGuard],
  },
];


app.config
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { KeycloakService, KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: '/auth',     // Use the proxy to route requests
        realm: 'my-realm',
        clientId: 'my-client',
      },
      initOptions: {
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        pkceMethod: 'S256',
        flow: 'standard',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200', // Your's redirectUri: `${baseURI}-angular/login`
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer'      
    });
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },
    importProvidersFrom(KeycloakAngularModule),
  ],
};

app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet], // Import RouterOutlet
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private keycloak: KeycloakService, private router: Router) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const isLoggedIn = await this.keycloak.isLoggedIn();
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      // Redirect to /profile if the user is authenticated
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    } else {
      // Trigger login if not authenticated
      await this.keycloak.login();
    }
  }
}

login.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  imports: [JsonPipe], // Import JsonPipe here
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.css'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  accessToken: any = null;

  constructor(private keycloak: KeycloakService) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      const token = await this.keycloak.getToken();
      this.accessToken = this.decodeToken(token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to retrieve tokens:', error);
    }
  }

  decodeToken(token: string): any {
    const parts = token.split('.');
    if (parts.length !== 3) {
      throw new Error('Invalid JWT token');
    }
    const payload = parts[1];
    return JSON.parse(atob(payload));
  }

  logout() {
    this.keycloak.logout();
  }
}

login.component.html
<p>login</p>
<p><strong>Decoded Access Token:</strong></p>
<pre>{{ accessToken | json }}</pre>
<button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>

Keycloak UI Setup

Username: user1
Password: 1234

Running Keycloak
Detail in here
Run Angular
ng serve


Access it by Browser
http://localhost:4200/login


Result
Display parsed Token after get access token


That's a great answer, but my problem resides not on the Angular side, but on the backend Java side.
I only have the client secret on the backend (Java), so I cannot retrieve the token on the Angular front.
I send the code to the backend, so that the token can be retrieved using the secret. But I don't have the code verifier.
Maybe the architecture is not the right one, but it's what I've understood to be the best option from what I've read.

This is example not a Java version but can handle own code_verifier by node.js in here OR other approach replace node_modules/keycloak-js files by source code with custom code can get code verifyer.

The PKCE code verifier is not something KeyCloak provides. Instead, it is a value that your client has to send to KeyCloak. It is all generated client-side, as shown in this picture below:

More details can be found here: Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)

I know that. I wanted to retrieve it from the KeycloakService in Angular
